# Silent cd using cdpath with zsh?

Tags: unix, zsh

When using `cd` to navigate to a path found by `cdpath` that is not located relative to `.`, the resulting path gets echoed. For example, assuming a directory structure like `~/parent/child` and a `cdpath` like `cdpath(~/parent)`, you see this:

```
$ cd parent
$ cd ~
$ cd child
~/parent/child
$
```

Basically, I want `cd child` to be silent, just like `cd ~/parent/child`, regardless of distance from the current directory. Is there a way to silence `cd` when it is using `cdpath` to locate and jump to a directory?

Comment: @Scott thanks for the cleanup–made my own question make more sense to myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that is hard-coded into the shell. Here's an excerpt from `builtin.c`:

```
if (isset(INTERACTIVE) || isset(POSIXCD)) {
    if (func != BIN_CD && isset(INTERACTIVE)) {
        if (unset(PUSHDSILENT) && !quiet)
            printdirstack();
    } else if (doprintdir) {
        fprintdir(pwd, stdout);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

`int doprintdir` is kind of a flag, which is set when using e.g. the `cdpath`.

So, if you really want to get rid of the printing of the new dir, comment out the `else if` part in the source -- with the disadvantage that you'll *never* get noticed anymore.

Comment: Ah, i was afraid this was the case.  Thanks for digging that up.

Answer (score 3):

Zsh 5.8 introduced an option for this purpose:

```
setopt cd_silent
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to roll your own `cd` function:

```
cd()
{
    if [ $# = 0 ]
    then
        builtin cd "$HOME"
        return
    fi
    # Use       if [[ "$1" =~ ^/ ]]
    # here if zsh supports it.
    case "$1" in
      /*)
        builtin cd "$1"
        return
    esac
    if [ -d "$1"  -a  -x "$1" ]
    then
        builtin cd "$1"
        # You might want this to return only if the cd succeeds.
        return
    fi
    for base in ~/parent /other/dir/thatIuse_a_lot
    do
        if builtin cd "$base/$1" 2> /dev/null
        then
            return
        fi
    done
    echo "$1: cd failed" >&2          # Customize to your liking.
    return 1                          # Indicate failure.
}
```

I don’t have access to a zsh right now, but I tested this in the Korn shell.  Of course you can enhance that to parse a `cdpath` variable at run time; I’ll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I considered this, but the idea of clobbering a builtin (especially one so central to shell interactions as ``cd``) scared me off. Still, lacking any alternatives (short of modifying the actual builtin), a truly robust version of this might make a good [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) contribution…

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, that works in sh, bash and zsh: `alias cd='cd >/dev/null'`

Also works for `cd -`.